# Simple IDE for Pascal for Linux

Tags: linux, ide, pascal

I am looking for a IDE for Pascal. Something that runs under Linux, is simple and easy to run. My goal is to setup something for a kid to learn, something that wouldn't require to derive from 10 classes to make a text visible on screen.

I remember DOS-based TurboPascal being very easy to use. Now I tried Lazarus, but its interface is very complex.

I don't need IDE that works with multiple languages, and I won't change Pascal into another language--there's lots of good textbooks in my native language for Pascal, and very little for other.

Thanks!

Comment: Pascal is kind of outdated these days. IMHO no longer a good first language choice since it has a very alien syntax (in comparison to commonly used languages).

Comment: I know it's based on Lazarus/FreePascal, but you might take a look into CodeTyphon, a powerful one click installation package for cross platform native Delphi like RAD/IDE based on Lazarus/FreePascal. If you don't need to create GUI applications then just select 'console application' in new application wizard. CodeTyphon also installs FreePascal and it's own character based editor, so you can always switch to it if you decide.
http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147

Comment: @avra: could you add this as an answer?

Comment: Let Me Be: a comment devoid of any real info, just unfounded opinions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) with its included editor or a basic text editor, like nano or gedit?  You could also use one of the old "Borland-ish" IDEs like [PENG](http://fjf.gnu.de/peng/) or [RHIDE](http://www.rhide.com/).

Comment: Ha, didn't notice that FreePascal itself comes with a editor. Thanks!

Comment: It does, start "fp" to run the (textmode) IDE

Answer (score 5):

Look here:

- http://www.freepascal.org/

More specific:

- http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/

You can try Eclipse plugin, which might work better for you:

- http://www.gavab.etsii.urjc.es/wiki/pascaline/

Also, try this one:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylix_(software)

This is not strictly Pascal, but Delphi was spun off from Pascal.

Comment: @syrion Sorry, I did not see that part... Thanks - I edited for one more

Comment: Lazarus too big, Kylix old and not supported anymore. For now I'll use freepascal's editor. I might check Pascaline later. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, Kylix seems supported, just not free: <http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934#>.

Comment: Once you get used to intellisense like functionality it is hard to go back. +1 for Lazarus.

Comment: icyrock: that is a presentation of internal projects at Embarcadero. It is not available yet, and it is not Kylix, but something new based on Kylix technology (a crosscompiler). As far as I understood, there will be no *nix or OS X IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run the original Turbo Pascal 7 inside Dos-Box.
Dos-Box is available for Linux and comes with Free-Dos installed.
Very good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

[Geany](https://www.geany.org/) is also good. It supports

- syntax highlighting
- symbol-name auto-completion (which is akin to intellisense)
- specifying compiler options
- integration with build tools

Among several other features one would expect in a modern integrated development environment.

Plus it's open source and runs across *nix, MacOSX and Windows.

Answer (score -1):

wrong on all counts. Embercardero has a community dev version for Sindows- ports to OSX, needs (an emu) some add-ons for linux. FP is the ported version of the old DOS app- with inheritance and classes--there really isnt something you seek. Its wither fp/rhide or Lazarus. You might want to brush up on UI programming or SDL. Im sorry but after ten + years of developing, Ive not seen anything "easier"- unless you write the code to make it easier. Pascal is far from dead. Further- you might try python. Four lines of code to a UI application(tkinter lib). TP7 is not a solution, fp ide is the same.